# Do exceptions caught and handled by programming languages count as software interrupts?

Tags: java, c++, exception, programming-languages, interrupt

From the beginning of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt, it says that a software interrupt can be caused by an exceptional condition in the processor itself (often called a trap or exception).

In many programming languages (C++, Java, Python,...), there are language supports for catching and handling exceptions defined by default, and also exceptions self-defined. For example, `try {...} catch ...`. Let me called both kinds of exceptions "language-supported exceptions" (because I don't know what is the right terminology).

1. Do the language-supported exceptions   count as software interrupts?
2. When a language-supported exception happens, does the same thing
   happen as for handling a software interrupt? Specifically, does the
   cpu save the current process into stacks, and then switch to run the
   OS kernel which then calls the exception handler, and after
   finishing running the handler, resume running the saved process?

Comment: I'd say probably not as it states 1) "exceptional enough that the programm can't handle the error itself" (which is not quite true for Java since at least the JVM will handle Java exceptions) and 2) software interrupts are using the processor to communicate those interrupts. So there certainly are error conditions in those languages that can cause interrupts but I'd say most exceptions that are handled internally are real interrupts.

Answer (score 5):

1. No, java language exception has nothing to do with software interrupts
2. Java language exception just initiates some exception handling code within same process and thread.

Answer (score 4):

No.

An interrupt causes an interrupt handler to be invoked. Once that handler is complete the original code will continue executing from the place it was at when the interrupt happened.

Exceptions are handled in a `catch` block. Program flow is directly affected.

From your link:

> The processor responds by **suspending its current activities, saving its state**, and executing a function called an interrupt handler (or an interrupt service routine, ISR) to deal with the event. This interruption is temporary, and, **after the interrupt handler finishes, the processor resumes normal activities**.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1 No.  As per your wiki reference one explanation is

> The former is often called a trap or exception and is used for
>   errors or events occurring during program execution that are
>   exceptional enough that they cannot be handled within the program
>   itself.

You are able to handle any Java exception within your program.  So that is one difference.  A Java exception could be triggered by an exceptional condition within the processor but the exception handler in your program is responding to an event generated within the JVM, not directly responding to a software interrupt.  The more conventional way to think of software interrputs is

> Software interrupt instructions function similarly to subroutine
>   calls and are used for a variety of purposes, such as to request
>   services from low-level system software such as device drivers.

Do a little research about how to invoke BIOS or MS/DOS services using the INT x86 instruction (this generates a software interrupt).

Questionn 2.  Not necessarily.  The JVM can generate an exception that has nothing to do with an exceptional processor condition.  Think null reference.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Exceptions don't count as software interrupts, nor do they act as software interrupts.

Specifically, language-supported exceptions don't *need* to call the operating system; a context switch is generally unnecessary.  Instead, throwing an exception makes a call to user-side code which understands how to look for handlers, unwind the call stack, and so forth, for that particular language.

To look at it another way:  a general-purpose operating system will not know or care about the language-specific details necessary to handle language-supported exceptions.  Software interrupts fall under the category of the operating system's [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface), which does not need to be remotely similar to the internal standards of a given language implementation.